# Meaning of で Before a Conjunction

Tags: copula, renyōkei

> ### めったに～ない
>
> ～するのはほとんどない。
>
> 〔例〕店長【てんちょう】は優しい【やさしい】人【ひと】**で**、めったに怒らない【おこらない】。
>
> 'The store manager is a nice person and rarely gets angry.'

What does で mean in this sentence?

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

This で is continuous form of a auxiliary verb だ that means "conclusion".

It is used when a sentence follows. For example, 私は日本人で、彼はアメリカ人だ。(I am Japanese and he is American.).

Comment: What do you mean when you say で means "conclusion"?

Comment: I mean 断定 because だ is 断定の助動詞. Are there other appropriate words for it?

Comment: @Blavius It's just the name for the copula in Japanese school grammar, although the name doesn't really make sense.